# Crystal convert string to hash from response.body

Tags: crystal-lang

I am going some HTTP gets and the response body is this structure:

```
response.body = "{\"temp\": \"val_one\", \"temp2\": \"val_two\"}"
```

How do I convert this to a Hash, I want to do this:

```
response.body.to_hash
response.body["temp"] # => val_one
```

Thanks

edit:

Fixed temp's value. Changed from val_one to \"val_one\"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That seems to be a JSON, so you should use [`JSON.parse`](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.19.4/JSON.html).

```
my_hash = JSON.parse response.body
my_hash["temp"] # => val_one
```

Pay attention to your data, though - `val_one` *as is* is not actually valid JSON. If it is a String, you should quote it (like you did with `val_two`).

Example in Crystal Play [here](https://play.crystal-lang.org/#/r/1ean).

Comment: My mistake, yes it should be a string. Thanks this works!